# Android onResume() not being called

Tags: java, android

for a while I have been creating a game engine that works on Android using Java. Unfortunately I have this problem where the onResume() method does't appear to be called. I am using a Thread to run everything, and when I minimise the app and then go back on the app, it just gives me a blank, black screen. But it DOES work when I turn the screen off and on again.

The code that I am using for the activity:

```
 package org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android;

 import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.Settings;
 import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android.input.AndroidInput;
 import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game.BaseGame;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.view.WindowManager;

 public abstract class AndroidActivity extends Activity {

/* The abstract methods*/
public abstract void activityCreated();
public abstract void activityPaused();
public abstract void activityResumed();
public abstract void activityStopped();
public abstract void activityRestarted();
public abstract void activityDestroy();

/* The android display */
public AndroidDisplay androidDisplay;

/* The onCreate method */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set the title
    this.setTitle(Settings.Window.Title);
    //Check the orientation and set it
    if (AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation == AndroidSettings.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    else if (AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation == AndroidSettings.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    //Check if the activity should be fullscreen
    if (Settings.Window.Fullscreen) {
        //Get rid of the title bar
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Make the activity fullscreen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

/* The onCreate method */
protected void onCreate(BaseGame androidGame , Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set the title
    this.setTitle(Settings.Window.Title);
    //Check the orientation and set it
    if (AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation == AndroidSettings.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    else if (AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation == AndroidSettings.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    //Check if the activity should be fullscreen
    if (Settings.Window.Fullscreen) {
        //Get rid of the title bar
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Make the activity fullscreen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    //Create the display
    androidDisplay = new AndroidDisplay(this , androidGame);
    //Set the content view
    this.setContentView(androidDisplay);
    //Call the activity create method
    this.activityCreated();
}

/* Called when the activity is paused */
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Pause the thread
    this.androidDisplay.androidGameThread.paused = true;
    //Call the method
    this.activityPaused();
}

/* Called when the activity is resumed */
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Resume the thread
    this.androidDisplay.androidGameThread.paused = false;
    //Call the method
    this.activityResumed();
}

/* Called when the activity is stopped */
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Call the method
    this.activityStopped();
}

/* Called when the activity is restarted */
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    //Call the method
    this.activityRestarted();
}

/* Called when the activity is destroyed */
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Call the method
    this.activityDestroy();
    //Destroy
    this.finish();
}
 }
```

The code that I am using for the thread:

```
package org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android;

import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game.BaseGame;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.input.InputManager;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class AndroidGameThread extends Thread {

/* Is the thread running */
public boolean running;

/* Is the thread paused */
public boolean paused;

/* The surface holder */
public SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

/* The android game */
public BaseGame androidGame;

/* The constructor */
public AndroidGameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder , BaseGame androidGame) {
    //Set running to false
    this.running = false;
    //Set paused to false
    this.paused = false;
    //Assign the surface holder
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    //Assign the android game
    this.androidGame = androidGame;
}

/* The method to set the running variable */
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

/* Returns whether the thread is running */
public boolean isRunning() {
    return this.running;
}

/* The run method */
public void run() {
    //Start the game
    this.androidGame.create();
    //Run while the variable running is true
    while (running) {
        //Check if the thread is paused
        if (! this.paused) {
            //Check the input
            InputManager.checkInput();
            //Set the game canvas to null
            AndroidStore.gameCanvas = null;
            //Try statement
            try {
                //Set the game canvas
                AndroidStore.gameCanvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (this.surfaceHolder) {
                    //Update/Render the game
                    this.androidGame.tick();
                }
            } finally {
                //Check that the canvas isn't null
                if (AndroidStore.gameCanvas != null) {
                    this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(AndroidStore.gameCanvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Also, to start the thread I use

```
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.Settings;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game.BaseGame;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.input.InputManager;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.ScreenUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class AndroidDisplay extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* The android game */
public BaseGame androidGame;

/* The android game thread */
public AndroidGameThread androidGameThread;

/* The constructor */
public AndroidDisplay(Activity gameActivity , BaseGame androidGame) {
    //Call the super constructor
    super(gameActivity);

    //Add the callback
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Set the game activity in the AndroidStore
    AndroidStore.gameActivity = gameActivity;

    //Set the android game
    this.androidGame = androidGame;

    //Create the android game thread
    this.androidGameThread = new AndroidGameThread(this.getHolder(), this.androidGame);

    //Set the surface view focusable
    this.setFocusable(true);
}

/* Called when the surface is created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //Create the input
    InputManager.create();
    //Set the size of the screen in the settings if full screen
    if (Settings.Window.Fullscreen) {
        Settings.Window.Size.Width = ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth();
        Settings.Window.Size.Height = ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight();
    } else {
        //Set the size of the screen in the settings
        Settings.Window.Size.Width = this.getWidth();
        Settings.Window.Size.Height = this.getHeight();
    }
    //Set the game resources
    AndroidStore.gameResources = this.getResources();
    //Create the game
    this.androidGame.gameCreated();
    //Create the paint object
    AndroidStore.gamePaint = new Paint();
    //Start the android game thread
    this.androidGameThread.setRunning(true);
    this.androidGameThread.start();
}

/* Called when the surface is changed */
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder , int format , int width , int height) {
    //Set the size of the screen in the settings
    Settings.Window.Size.Width = ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth();
    Settings.Window.Size.Height = ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight();
}

/* Called when the surface is destroyed */
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //Should the loop continue
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        //Try and catch statement
        try {
            //Stop the game
            this.androidGame.gameStopped();
            //Close the game
            this.androidGame.gameClosing();
            //Join the thread
            this.androidGameThread.join();
            //Stop the while loop
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

}
```

To run all of this I have a class that 'extends' AndroidActvity and uses the following method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Settings.Window.Title = "MyEngine Android Tests";
    Settings.Android = true;
    Settings.Video.OpenGL = false;
    Settings.Audio.SoundEffectVolume = 10;
    AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation = 1;
    Settings.Window.Fullscreen = true;
    this.onCreate(new FileTest() ,  savedInstanceState);
}
```

The testing class:

```
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.Settings;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android.AndroidActivity;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android.AndroidSettings;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Settings.Window.Title = "MyEngine Android Tests";
    Settings.Android = true;
    Settings.Video.OpenGL = false;
    Settings.Audio.SoundEffectVolume = 10;
    AndroidSettings.ScreenOrientation = 1;
    Settings.Window.Fullscreen = true;
    this.onCreate(new FileTest() ,  savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void activityCreated() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void activityPaused() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("HELLO", "I HAVE BEEN PAUSED");
}

@Override
public void activityResumed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("HELLO", "I HAVE BEEN RESUMED");
}

@Override
public void activityStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("HELLO", "I HAVE BEEN STOPPED");
}

@Override
public void activityRestarted() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("HELLO", "I HAVE BEEN RESTARTED");
}

@Override
public void activityDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("HELLO", "I HAVE BEEN DESTROYED");
}

}
```

FileTest:

```
package com.simplecorporation.myengine.android.tests;

import java.util.List;

import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.Settings;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.audio.clip.AndroidAudio;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game.BaseGame;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game2d.entity.ImageEntity2D;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUIButton;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUICheckBox;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUIRenderer;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUIScrollBar;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUISlider;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.GUITextDisplayArea;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.font.GUIFont;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.font.bitmap.BitmapFont;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.image.Image;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.input.event.TouchEvent;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.render.basic.BasicRenderer;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.render.colour.Colour;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.AndroidFileUtils;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.ArrayUtils;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.FileUtils;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.font.FontUtils;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileTest extends BaseGame {

public ImageEntity2D image;
public Colour colour;
public GUIButton button;
public GUICheckBox checkBox;
public AndroidAudio audio;
public GUIFont bitmapFont;
public GUIScrollBar scrollBar;

public GUIScrollBar verticalslider;
public GUIScrollBar horizontalslider;
public GUITextDisplayArea textDisplayArea;

public FileTest() {
    createGame();
}

@Override
public void gameCreated() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    image = new ImageEntity2D(new Image(R.drawable.menubutton));
    image.position.x = 200;
    image.position.y = 200;
    image.width = 200;
    image.height = 60;
    image.rotationVelocity = 1;
    colour = new Colour(0d, 0d, 0d, 1d);
    button = new GUIButton("AndroidGUIButton" , "Click Me" , new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] {
            Colour.LIGHT_BLUE , Colour.ORANGE , Colour.BLUE
    } , FontUtils.buildGUIFont("Arial" , Colour.WHITE , 46f)));
    button.position.x = 300;
    button.position.y = 200;
    button.width = 300;
    button.height = 60;
    button.visible = true;

    checkBox = new GUICheckBox("AndroidCheckBox" , new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] { Colour.WHITE , Colour.BLUE }));
    checkBox.position.x = 500;
    checkBox.position.y = 300;
    checkBox.width = 100;
    checkBox.height = 100;
    checkBox.visible = true;

    bitmapFont = new GUIFont(new BitmapFont(new Image(R.drawable.test) , 40, 16));

    GUIButton verticalsliderButton = new GUIButton("Button2" , "" , new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] {
            Colour.ORANGE ,
            Colour.LIGHT_BLUE ,
            Colour.BLUE
    } , FontUtils.buildGUIFont("Segoe UI" , Colour.WHITE , 20f)));
    verticalsliderButton.width = 100;
    verticalsliderButton.height = 20;
    verticalsliderButton.visible = true;

    verticalslider = new GUIScrollBar("Slider1" , verticalsliderButton , GUISlider.DIRECTION_VERTICAL , 1, new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] { Colour.RED }));

    verticalslider.visible = true;
    verticalslider.position.x = 200;
    verticalslider.position.y = 200;
    verticalslider.width = 30;
    verticalslider.height = 100;

    GUIButton horizontalsliderButton = new GUIButton("Button2" , "" , new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] {
            Colour.ORANGE ,
            Colour.LIGHT_BLUE ,
            Colour.BLUE
    } , FontUtils.buildGUIFont("Segoe UI" , Colour.WHITE , 20f)));
    horizontalsliderButton.width = 20;
    horizontalsliderButton.height = 100;
    horizontalsliderButton.visible = true;

    horizontalslider = new GUIScrollBar("Slider2" , horizontalsliderButton , GUISlider.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL , 1, new GUIRenderer(new Colour[] { Colour.RED }));

    horizontalslider.visible = true;
    horizontalslider.position.x = 300;
    horizontalslider.position.y = 300;
    horizontalslider.width = 100;
    horizontalslider.height = 30;

    audio = new AndroidAudio(R.raw.encode , false , false);

    List<String> text = ArrayUtils.toStringList(new String[] {
            "Hello, this test application was made using MyEngine " + Settings.EngineVersion,
            "with the build " + Settings.EngineBuild + ". Below this message you should find",
            "a bitmap font:"
    });
    this.textDisplayArea = new GUITextDisplayArea("TextArea", text, FontUtils.buildGUIFont("Arial" , Colour.WHITE , 40f), Settings.Window.Size.Width);
    this.textDisplayArea.position.x = 0;
    this.textDisplayArea.position.y = 500;
    this.textDisplayArea.visible = true;

    AndroidFileUtils.writeToInternalStorage("hello.txt", ArrayUtils.toStringList(new String[] {
            "Hello World, From hello.txt"
    }));
    this.textDisplayArea.setText(AndroidFileUtils.readFromInternalStorage("hello.txt"));

    AndroidFileUtils.writeToExternalStorage("hello.txt", ArrayUtils.toStringList(new String[] {
            "Hello World, From hello.txt in an External Storage file :)"
    }));

    this.textDisplayArea.setText(FileUtils.read("eclipse.txt", false));

    Log.d("HELLO", "" + AndroidFileUtils.isExternalStorageWritable() + " " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
}

public void gameRender() {
    BasicRenderer.setColour(colour);
    BasicRenderer.renderFilledRectangle(0 , 0 , Settings.Window.Size.Width , Settings.Window.Size.Height);
    BasicRenderer.setColour(Colour.BLUE);
    BasicRenderer.renderFilledRectangle(100 , 100 , 100 , 100);
    BasicRenderer.setColour(Colour.WHITE);
    verticalslider.render();
    horizontalslider.render();
    image.render();
    button.render();
    checkBox.render();
    textDisplayArea.render();
    BasicRenderer.setColour(Colour.WHITE);
    bitmapFont.render("This is a bitmap font :)" , 10 , 700);
}

public void gameUpdate() {
    button.update();
    checkBox.update();
    image.update();
    verticalslider.update();
    horizontalslider.update();
    if (button.clicked) {
        colour = new Colour(0d , 0d , 0d , 1d);
        audio.play();
    }
    textDisplayArea.update();
}

public void onTouch(TouchEvent e) {
    this.colour = new Colour(this.colour.getR() + 0.01, this.colour.getG() + 0.01, this.colour.getB() + 0.01);
}

}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is your thread running? 
You havent called 
   androidDisplay.start();
method in your code

Comment: Have you put any logging statements in onResume to verify that it isn't being called?

Comment: Yes, in the AndroidDisplay class I use   this.androidGameThread.setRunning(true);
this.androidGameThread.start();

Comment: I have tried putting a log there, that is why I think it isn't being called.

Comment: Also, can you explain the overloading of onCreate() Method of your Activity?
Correct me if i am wrong . I think when the Activity is created 
Activity.onCreate(Bundle bun) is called . And this method doesn't creates any thread .

Comment: I have got two methods, onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) and the other is onCreate(BaseGame androidGame, Bundle savedInstanceState), I have one class that extends the AndroidActivity shown above and the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) is called by Android, then in this method that is overridden, I call the other one and pass an instance of BaseGame to it and therefore calls the other method. So in the test I have made I am using within the overridden onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method the code: this.onCreate(new FileTest() ,  savedInstanceState);

Comment: can you add full code of your testing class ?

Comment: this.onCreate(new FileTest() ,  savedInstanceState);
 will call 
     oncreateMethod( BaseGame androidGame , Bundle savedInstanceState) 

OF YOUR TESTING CLASS

Comment: Yes, I have a class called MainActivity that extends AndroidActivity and FileTest which extends BaseGame, they are separate classes. I have tested it and it does work as expected until, I go away from the app and then go back to it.

Comment: Quick update, tested again, it does work when turning the screen off and on, and when going away from the app it eventually says that it is not responding as if the thread never restarted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you everyone :)
I have spent the whole day trying to fix this issue and I have just fixed the problem.

I found this [Android onResume not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689316/android-onresume-not-called?rq=1), and then I added some calls to Log.d() to try and figure out what was happening. By adding them to each method in AndroidDisplay and AndroidActvity, I noticed that when I turned the screen off and on, I had the output: 'ACTIVITY PAUSED', 'ACTIVITY STOPPED', 'ACTIVITY RESTARTED', and 'ACTIVITY RESUMED' which was what I had expected, then when clicking on the menu button, there was an extra output, 'SURFACE DESTROYED' and so I changed AndroidDisplay, to stop the thread from stopping when the surface was destroyed so I moved that code into a method called stopThread() and then I found that I had a problem with the fact that I was re-creating the same thread twice because of the surfaceCreated() method in AndroidDisplay, so then I made an if statement before calling androidGameThread.start() which used androidGameThread.isAlive() therefore fixing this issue.

New AndroidDisplay code:

```
package org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.android;

import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.Settings;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.game.BaseGame;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.input.InputManager;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.ScreenUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class AndroidDisplay extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* The android game */
public BaseGame androidGame;

/* The android game thread */
public AndroidGameThread androidGameThread;

/* The boolean that states whether this has been created */
public boolean created;

/* The constructor */
public AndroidDisplay(Activity gameActivity , BaseGame androidGame) {
    //Call the super constructor
    super(gameActivity);

    //Add the callback
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Set the game activity in the AndroidStore
    AndroidStore.gameActivity = gameActivity;

    //Set the android game
    this.androidGame = androidGame;

    //Create the android game thread
    this.androidGameThread = new AndroidGameThread(this.getHolder(), this.androidGame, this);

    //Set created to false
    this.created = false;

    //Set the surface view focusable
    this.setFocusable(true);
}

/* Called when the surface is created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //Set created to true
    this.created = true;
    //Create the input
    InputManager.create();
    //Set the size of the screen in the settings if full screen
    if (Settings.Window.Fullscreen) {
        Settings.Window.Size.Width = ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth();
        Settings.Window.Size.Height = ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight();
    } else {
        //Set the size of the screen in the settings
        Settings.Window.Size.Width = this.getWidth();
        Settings.Window.Size.Height = this.getHeight();
    }
    //Set the game resources
    AndroidStore.gameResources = this.getResources();
    //Create the game
    this.androidGame.gameCreated();
    //Create the paint object
    AndroidStore.gamePaint = new Paint();
    //Start the android game thread if it has not already started
    this.androidGameThread.setRunning(true);
    if (! this.androidGameThread.isAlive())
        this.androidGameThread.start();
}

/* Called when the surface is changed */
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder , int format , int width , int height) {
    //Set the size of the screen in the settings
    Settings.Window.Size.Width = ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth();
    Settings.Window.Size.Height = ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight();
    //Reassign the surface holder
    this.androidGameThread.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
}

/* Called when the surface is destroyed */
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //Set created to false
    this.created = false;
}

/* The method used to stop the thread */
public void stopThread() {
    //Should the loop continue
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        //Try and catch statement
        try {
            //Stop the game
            this.androidGame.gameStopped();
            //Close the game
            this.androidGame.gameClosing();
            //Join the thread
            this.androidGameThread.join();
            //Stop the while loop
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Manifest, use this in launcher activity

```
android:noHistory="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly issue could me method overloading of Activity.onCreate() Method.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

This method (which will be called when activity is created.) doesn't create any thread .

I dont know if following method will be called when activity is created

```
 protected void onCreate(BaseGame androidGame , Bundle savedInstanceState)
```